# React Native nested horizontal scrollview not scrolling on Android

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I am working for a screen design it has like tinder swipe. But i can not use a horizontal scroll inside of this swiper. It is working on iOS devices, just it has on android side.

nestedScrollEnabled prop didnt solve to this issue.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} horizontal={true} style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} horizontal={true} style={{width: 200,}}>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test1</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test2</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test3</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test4</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test5</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test6</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test7</Text>
      </ScrollView>
      <Text>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Also you can check from snack.expo.io, https://snack.expo.io/tYAezkclc

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} horizontal={true} style={{width: 200,}}>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test1</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test2</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test3</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test4</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test5</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test6</Text>
        <Text style={{margin: 10}}>test7</Text>
      </ScrollView>
      <Text>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes it will work because first scrollview is not horizontal, my issue about nested horizontal scrollview